# ¿Como enviar datos desde el controlador a la vista con Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy usando nodejs y tengo una duda, no se como mostrar los datos de una tabla en una vista:(

En mi controlador tengo esta funcion

```
show: function(req,res){
    Student.findAll().then((students) => {
        res.render('students/show', {students: students});
    })
}
```

Para renderizar estoy usando el motor ejs. Lo que quiero es poder mostrar los elementos del arreglo en una vista en forma de lista.

Gracias por la atención

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te muestro como lo hago.

acá en el archivo routes agregué esto:

```
 const User = require('../models/user');
    router.get('/all-users', async (req, res, next) => {
    
      try {
    
        let users = await User.find();
        res.render('users/all-users', { users });
    
      } catch (e) {
        next(e);
      }
    });
```

Con EJS creo la vista donde quiero mostrar los datos, llamando a otras vistas que arman la página.

```
<%- layout('layouts/main') %>


<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-10 pt-5 mx-auto">
    <ul>
        <% users.forEach(function(user) { %>
            <li style="list-style-type: none;">
                <span><%= user.email %></span>
            </li>
        <% }); %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<%- include('../partials/leftmenu'); %>
```

Espero te funcione.